# How to load new fragment in same space as current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to handle fragments which launch other fragments.

I'm converting an app which I started writing using a more Activity based approach and have since begun moving it over to using Fragments.  I have some Fragments which used to launch a new Activity and I want to move them over to launching other Fragments in the same view that the current Fragment is residing.

For example - I have an Activity which has a WebView which uses a `WebViewClient` to handle internal js->java interactions.  My WebViewClient can launch other Activities, which I used to do with :

```
 i = new Intent(context, GoogleMapActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

This webview activity can either be fullscreen or in a view with a menu on the side, but I want the webview to respect the layout - so if the menu is present, it should stay present when launching new Fragments - I just don't know the best approach to writing the code which launches the Fragments.

So...is there a way, within a Fragment, of essentially telling a new Fragment to load in to the same space as the current Fragment or does there need to be some interaction with the Activity?

** EDIT **

Given that there are a few different layouts which could be used, I don't always know which id I should be targeting to put the fragment in - hence I need to know if there's a way to do this without knowing the id (as in the `replace` method for example).

Comment: look at this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790945/how-can-i-use-fragmentmanager-to-display-fragment-a-b-c-in-a-framelayout/7791116#7791116

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
   .replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(), fragment)
   .addToBackStack(null)
   .commit();
```

This should replace parent container with desired fragment.

Answer (score 0):

That should be doable via `FragementManager.replace()`. Have a look at the [documentation for Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Layout) and especially the longer example in the "Layout" section there.

Comment: Given that there are a few different layouts which could be used, I don't always know which id I should be targeting to put the fragment in - hence I need to know if there's a way to do this without knowing the id.  Or what approach I should use - ie should I name all fragments with the same id?

Comment: you can also get the fragment with the tag. after that in the replace instead of id , you can pass first argument as fragment.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add Fragment rather replace it, use:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment()).commit();
```