# recylerview onclick listview open new fragments

Tags: android

I am using tabbed activity which has 3 tab in it one tab contain RecylerView of list and if I click on on list it should open new tab or fragment in tabbed activity

this is my adapter class

```
public class tabAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<tabAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater lf;


List<information> data = Collections.emptyList();

private Context context;




public tabAdapter(Context context,List<information> data){

   this.context=context;
   lf=LayoutInflater.from(context);
   this.data=data;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = lf.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.res,parent,false);

    MyViewHolder ms = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return ms;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    information info=data.get(position);

    holder.tx.setText(info.str);
    holder.tm.setImageResource(info.img);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tx;
    ImageView tm;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        tx = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ids);
        tm = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imag);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,tab3.class));

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Where does your code fail?

Comment: onClick method m directly calling fragment that is not working when i tryied with different activity its working

Comment: so m not getting how to call new fragment  on onClick method how to do so?

Comment: is tab3.class is a Fragment ?

Comment: yes tab3 is fragment so that y m not directly able to open it

Comment: Then load new Fragment or update new Fragment for viewpager(if applicable). Only activity can be created with startActivity() method

Comment: when i click on my recylerview i want new fragment to open on one off my tab in tabbed activity

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29670160/1292557

Answer (score 0):

Define a listener in your RecyclerView Adapter

and override that in your activity to change tabs

```
public class tabAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<tabAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater lf;

    interface MyListener {
        void changeTabs();
    }

    MyListener listener;

    public void setListener(MyListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    List<information> data = Collections.emptyList();

    private Context context;


    public tabAdapter(Context context, List<information> data) {

        this.context = context;
        lf = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = lf.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.res, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder ms = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return ms;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        information info = data.get(position);

        holder.tx.setText(info.str);
        holder.tm.setImageResource(info.img);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.changeTabs();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tx;
        ImageView tm;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            tx = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ids);
            tm = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imag);
        }

    }
}
```

on override in your activity like this :

```
List<information> data = new ArrayList<>();
....
    tabAdapter tabAdapter = new tabAdapter(data);
    tabAdapter.setListener(new MyListener() {
        @Override
        public void changeTabs() {
            // change tabs
        }
    });
```

Comment: sir when i click on the listitem of recylerview then only i want to go to different fragments

Comment: @ShubhamDangare Yes exactly it will do it for you, but because you can't access your fragments from RecyclerView adapter we use Listener and override it from activity