# Fragments inside Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image]

In above diagram, i want to ask about Fragment.
 if there is one button in fragment 2 , click on button and it start fragment 3.
 one more button on fragment3 ,click on that come back to fragment 2.

Can someone tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) to manage fragments in second one.

Simply start new fragment in "fragment 2" placeholder and by pressing button in fragment 3 - go back to fragment 2.

Also check this link: [How can I use FragmentManager to display Fragment A, B, C,... in a FrameLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790945/how-can-i-use-fragmentmanager-to-display-fragment-a-b-c-in-a-framelayout)

Comment: i used FragmentTransaction  but ,what ever there in fragment 2 is display in fragment 3

Comment: do you mean the same data? Than you can load and store data in your fragments but not in fragmentActivity

Comment: in fragment 2 i used (3 textview , button),when i click button it comes to fragment 3 id display (4 textview ,2 button) . the text and button what are there in fragment 2 also

Answer (score 0):

"Fragments inside Fragments" is not a good description for this case. You will first have a parent `FragmentActivity` which holds the fragment. Fragment 1 has nothing to do in your case, so just leave it for now.

The button at fragment 2 asks the `FragmentActivity` to add a new fragment to the screen using `FragmentManager`. You want to add this step to the back stack by using `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)`, so you can go back to fragment 2 later.

The button at fragment 3 asks the `FragmentActivity` to remove itself from the screen by using `FragmentManager.popBackStack()`. It is like the go back button of your browser.