# Android Studio multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm designing a music player app and this is my second time working with android studio and fragments in general. I've watched a lot of tutorial videos on this but I'm having trouble getting multiple fragments to show. Maybe using fragments isn't the way of going about this. But basically what I have right now is a fixed menu at the top and 5 fragments just below it (on top of each other).

What I was hoping to do was by clicking each button one fragment would load so you would have one activity but 5 fragments that load when buttons are pressed. But the issue i'm having right now is instead of stopping one fragment and loading another one, they're being loaded on top of each other. Is there a way to go about doing this?

Below is an image of the design I had in mind. The blue box is where the five fragments are and right now they're overlapping. Any help would be appreciated :)

[image: Design]

EDIT: Turns out the answer was I needed to define one layout for all of the fragments. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You want to use the fragmentmanager http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790945/how-can-i-use-fragmentmanager-to-display-fragment-a-b-c-in-a-framelayout. API doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Comment: post your code....!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please post code. But here's what I can make out so far from your problem,

I assume you are just using `FragmentManager.beginTransaction.add()` again and again.

If it is the case please change your code to

```
FragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
    containerViewID,
    new FragmentYouWantToReplace
);
```

What this does is removes previous fragment and adds this new fragment.

So you can have your default fragment using add() during activity load, but for each button click you use replace().

Answer (score 0):

When you call a new fragment you should replace always the same layout, the one you want to show the information, like this:

```
frag_results frag_results = new frag_results();
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout_secundary, frag_results, frag_results.getTag()).commit();
```